# Reboot ubuntu without a complete hardware reboot

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, reboot, runlevel

I would like to reboot the OS as if it is pulled up from GRUB, but without actually rebooting the entire computer. This is because this machine has a bunch of different OSes on it and while a reboot is necessary human interaction for boot options selection is not under this scenario. Any ideas? I know you can drop down to various run-levels but I am not aware of (lets call it) "an incomplete software-reboot".

Comment: Do you know virtualbox ?! with this program you could use several distros without to reboot your machine - and change from one to the other - with vmware (something different program - but no freeware ) it is possible to change the desktop with keyboard-shortcuts from one to the other, without switching off the running systems.

Comment: I do indeed. Great program, but it does not solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  **kexec** command it seems to do exactly what you need.

```
kexec -l kernel-image --append=command-line-options --initrd=initrd-image
```

from kexec manpage :

kexec is a system call that enables you to load and boot into 
    another kernel from the currently running kernel. kexec performs 
    the function of the boot loader from within the kernel. The primary
     difference between a standard system boot and a kexec boot is that
     the **hardware initialization** normally performed by the BIOS or 
    firmware (depending on architecture) **is not performed during a kexec
     boot**. This has the effect of reducing the time required for a reboot.
...
Insert the command-line parameters that must be passed to the new kernel into `command-line-options`. Passing the exact contents of `/proc/cmdline` into `command-line-options` is the safest way to ensure that correct values are passed to the rebooting kernel.

*Never tried **kexec** myself (except maybe during crashdump to load the dump kernel, but it was an automatic process), I would go to single user mode first to stop all the processes before running kexec .*